# Add my python script to the system tray? Or the start menu, to run mu simple GUI?

Tags: python, ubuntu, kde-plasma

I'm just starting out with python. I have written a litte script/program/bit of code that is a GUI to change my keyboard brightness.

I'd like to add the 'program' I wrote to the applications menu, or even better have it run from the system tray.

Can anybody tell me how to turn my program into a stand alone icon that I can double click to run. I have looked online at 'compiling', 'making stand-alone' etc. I don't know the words to describe what I want to do.

I'm running Ubuntu with KDE desktop.

I doubt it's relevant but my code is:

```
## GUI for adjusting keyboard back-light
## Opens the config file, writes config file, closes file.
#!/usr/bin/env python
def open_and_write():
    myfile = open("/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/"\
                "leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness", "wb")
    myfile.write(x)
    myfile.close()
def press_off():
    global x
    x = "0"
    open_and_write()
def press_medium():
    global x
    x = "1"
    open_and_write()
def press_full():
    global x
    x = "2"
    open_and_write()
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()                 
root.title("Backlight")
root.geometry("228x122")    
app = Frame(root)           
app.grid()                  
button1 = Button(app, text = "Off", width=6, height=5, command=press_off)
button2 = Button(app, text = "Medium", width=6, height=5, command=press_medium)
button3 = Button(app, text = "Full", width=6, height=5,command=press_full)
button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
button3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
button = Button(root, text='EXIT', width=25, pady=5, command=root.destroy)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()*
```

Comment: off-topic question: why use a global? You never seem to care about `x` except inside the `press_*` functions and `open_and_write`. Make `open_and_write` accept `x` as an argument and do away with the global.

Comment: Maybe something like this https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57943-Adding-launchers-to-the-system-tray ?

Comment: @whrrgarbl ahhh I had misread the question. I thought he was trying to minimize to the system tray, not simply have a shortcut there!

Comment: @AdamSmith took me a couple times re-reading too :) Unfortunately I can't run KDE to test anything but hopefully it's a pointer in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will investigate the "ksystraycmd" command mentioned in the other post. --- can you elaborate of how I make opan_and_write accept x as an argument? Using the global line is ugle but I don;t know another way to do it. --- This is my second day with python!

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy in KDE.

Right click your KDE application menu, no mater KDE 4 or 5. Choose "Edit applications...". And you will see a list of all applications.

Choose a category, like "System", and create an application menu entry.

You need to give a name and specify the path of your script. Optionally, you can select an icon for it.

Then just save it.

Open application menu, you could find your application icon.

Document: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/quickstart.html

If you want desktop shortcut, just drag the icon in app menu to your desktop.

If you want task bar shortcut, run the application and right click on task bar, select "Pin" or "Show when not running" or something.